# windows firewall on windows server 2008 + mail server

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, firewall, email-server

i configured and installed MDaemon in my **web server** (with iis and dns installed) for getting mail server too.
web admin and web client are working perfect.
my problem is about server firewall and security!

**Q#1 :**
when both windows firewall and nod 32 are off on server , i can send and recieve emails.
i activated 25 & 110 & 143 port numbers in nod 32 / so when nod 32 firewall is on every thing is ok...
but i want to learn which part of windows firewall should i change for recieve and send emails? (when windows firewall is on i only can send emails and i don't know where can i find incoming emails that have been blocked by windows firewall)

**Q#2 :**
where can i find incoming emails that have been blocked by windows firewall?

**Q#3 :**
after making that firewall comfortable for mail server , what can i do about it's security?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Windows firewall doesn't harvest emails. If the firewall blocks incoming connections (inbound emails) to port 25 then no email is delivered, so there's no email to find.You need to allow the same ports in the Windows firewall that you did in nod32: Port 25 inbound (for incoming email), port 110 inbound (for incoming user connections via POP to retieve emails from their mailboxes), port 143 inbound (for incoming user connections via IMAP to retieve emails from their mailboxes), possibly port 80 and port 443 inbound (for incoming user conections to web based email if you have that configured).
2. See answer number 1.
3. After configuring the firewall you can run the Security Configuration Wizard to further harden the server. In fact, the SCW will configure the firewall as part of it's process, based on selections you choose during the SCW process.

Comment: thanks for answer / would u plz get me some direction to enabling 25,143,110 ports in firewall? (such as start menu->control panel->administrators-> ...) / my Q#2 was about MDaemon , is there a way to view blocked emails ? / thanks for helping me...